# Backspace makes input not populate using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have an input tag like this:

```
<input ng-model='number'>
```

and a bunch of buttons that populate this input:

```
<a class='btn' ng-click='pop(1)'>1</a>
```

This is the pop function:

```
$rootScope.pop = function(number) {
    $rootScope.number = $scope.number + number;
}
```

The buttons and all populate the model and input correctly, but if I use the backspace key on the keyboard to erase what's currently in the input, clicking the button will no longer populate and display the input field.

I've tried making an event listener for when the backspace key is pressed and handling backspace using a custom function, but that didn't work. Any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue above.
Apparently this was due to an angular scoping issue.

Instead of using $rootScope.number, I created an object and set the property of the object as number.

For example:
`$rootScope.obj.number`

---

Using the property of the object fixed the issue, just needed to do a little reading on angular scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Add a pre-check before adding the number to see if it is null or undefined. When you erase the input field, the var `number` is `undefined` or `""`

```
$rootScope.pop = function(number) {
    // !== Compares two expressions to determine if they are not equal in value or of the same data type
    if($rootScope.number !== undefined && $rootScope.number !== null){
        //Added "" just to make sure the number is treated like a string
        $rootScope.number = "" + $rootScope.number + number;
    } else {
        $rootScope.number = "" + number;
    }
}
```

And in the code define `$rootScope.number` as `string`

```
$rootScope.number = "";
```

Comment: This doesn't work, what I realized is, after I press buttons for 1, 2, 3, $rootScope.number = 123. After I erase the numbers on the input, I would expect $rootScope.number to be equal to undefined or "", but it is still 123.

Comment: Do you want to be `123` after press the 1 2 3 buttons or '6'?

Comment: 123, basically i have a dialpad, each button adds a digit to $scope.number which is the model of the input using the pop function.

Comment: I changed the answer based on your comments, check if it's working for you.

Comment: I tried all the things that i told you and works.... You are doing something wrong in another place